# ItemTouchHelper on MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement delete `onSwiped` to my `RecyclerView`, but I'm not sure if I should implement in the `view` of inside the `adapter`.

I'm trying now to do it on my `Fragment`, but for some reasons, Android Studio doesn't show the `attachToRecyclerView()` method from my `ItemTouchHelper`

Here my `ItemTouchHelper`

```
class RecyclerItemTouchHelper(var viewModel: DayTrackerViewModel, var adapter : DayAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ){

    lateinit private var _adapter : DayAdapter
    lateinit private var _viewModel : DayTrackerViewModel

    init {
        _adapter = adapter
        _viewModel = viewModel
    }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        _viewModel.deleteDay(viewHolder.itemId)
        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And here my `Fragment`

```
class DaysTrackerFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var itemTouchHelper : RecyclerItemTouchHelper
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding: DaysTrackerFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.days_tracker_fragment, container, false
        )
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource = DayDatabase.getInstance(application).dayDatabaseDao
        val viewModelFactory = DayTrackerViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(DayTrackerViewModel::class.java)

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        val adapter = DayAdapter(DayAdapter.DayListener { _ ->
            viewModel.onDayClicked()
        })

        itemTouchHelper = RecyclerItemTouchHelper(viewModel, adapter)
        binding.dayList.adapter = adapter

        // itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView -> Doesn't get the method

        viewModel.eventSaveButtonPressed.observe(this, Observer { hasBeenPressed ->
            if (hasBeenPressed) {
                viewModel.createDayAndInsert(binding.dayInput2.text.toString(), binding.activityInput.text.toString())
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: Hi Denny, welcome to Stack overflow. If your question has been answered then please click tick icon besides the answer instead of adding [SOLVED] to the title of your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`, not `ItemTouchHelper` itself. If you look at [the docs for the Callback class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html) you can see that there's no `attachRecyclerView(..)` method on it.

Comment: You are very right! My bad, so by making a new `ItemTouchHelper` object and passing my `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback' in the constructor I should be able to use the `attachRecyclerView()` method.

Thank you very much :)